# fs.copy is not creating a directory, Node.js - fs.extra

Tags: node.js, fs

Have issues with fs.copy from the fs-extra [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra).

```
fs.copy('/Library/WebServer/Documents/ewa-mypdb/backend/uploads/project/4/products/1506', '/Library/WebServer/Documents/ewa-mypdb/backend/uploads/project/4/products/test', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
})
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: EISDIR, read
```

This error occurs when the target expects is something else than a directory. And thats exactly what it is:

[image]

Its some sort of file that is created instead of a directory. And it's the copy function that creates the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get it. What is the actual problem? You already have a file with the same name as the target directory and you still want to copy. Am I right?

Comment: No, target directory does not exist. The 'test' file is created by the fs.copy when it should have created a directory instead.

Comment: This looks like a bug in fs-extra, open a bug report in the issue tracker.

Comment: fs-extra author here. Which version of `fs-extra` are you using? Which version of Node.js are you using? Which version of Mac OS X?